# onAttach() in the compatibility library ListFragment

Tags: android, android-compatibility

I want to override the onAttach() http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onAttach(android.app.Activity)  method of a ListFragment from the compatibility library, but it seems it can't be found...
am I getting something wrong, or maybe this method is not implemented in the compatibility library and I will have to override another method?List

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried to override:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onAttach(activity);
}
```

where I should have override:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(SupportActivity activity) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onAttach(activity);
}
```

Notice the: "Activity" of the first method and the: "SupportActivity" of the second..